# Why does independence matter in Statistics & Why does a MLM change Fixed Effect Coefficients?

Tags: anova, generalized-linear-model, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, independence

I've been trying to get a better grasp of statistics lately, and have been wondering why exactly independent observations matter when building a model? This is a broad question, but I'm curious about the math behind the idea and also interested in tying the concept to an application.

In my efforts, I have been experimenting with the `ChickWeight` dataset in R. This dataset contains repeated measures of chickens at different times while eating different diets. The main question of this data set is, *"Does diet have an effect on weight?"*

I'm hoping this application narrows down my question.

I have run two different models, one **not** accounting for repeated measures and another that **does** account for repeated measures in the data.

Why are the fixed effect coefficients different for both models?

What is it about accounting for repeated measures that changes the fixed effect coefficients?

If the coefficients didn't change, would that indicate that there is no strong interdependence in the observations?

Is there a way to see this change in the diagnostic plots of the model?

Here is my code:

```r
library(lme4)

head(ChickWeight)
#> Grouped Data: weight ~ Time | Chick
#>   weight Time Chick Diet
#> 1     42    0     1    1
#> 2     51    2     1    1
#> 3     59    4     1    1
#> 4     64    6     1    1
#> 5     76    8     1    1
#> 6     93   10     1    1

dependent.glm <- glm(weight ~ Diet, data = ChickWeight, 
                      family = Gamma(link = 'log'))

summary(dependent.glm)
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = weight ~ Diet, family = Gamma(link = "log"), data = ChickWeight)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
#> -1.0694  -0.5614  -0.1212   0.3113   1.3284  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  4.63128    0.03788 122.256  < 2e-16 ***
#> Diet2        0.17778    0.06376   2.788  0.00548 ** 
#> Diet3        0.33121    0.06376   5.194 2.86e-07 ***
#> Diet4        0.27594    0.06411   4.304 1.97e-05 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for Gamma family taken to be 0.3157066)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 193.02  on 577  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 182.34  on 574  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 6372.4
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5

par(mfrow = c(2,2))
plot(dependent.glm)
```

[image]

```r
independent.glm <- glmer(weight ~ Diet + (1 | Chick), data = ChickWeight, 
                          family = Gamma(link = 'log'))

summary(independent.glm)
#> Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace
#>   Approximation) [glmerMod]
#>  Family: Gamma  ( log )
#> Formula: weight ~ Diet + (1 | Chick)
#>    Data: ChickWeight
#> 
#>      AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
#>   6344.1   6370.2  -3166.0   6332.1      572 
#> 
#> Scaled residuals: 
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -1.4614 -0.8268 -0.1679  0.7333  2.8152 
#> 
#> Random effects:
#>  Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
#>  Chick    (Intercept) 0.02743  0.1656  
#>  Residual             0.26793  0.5176  
#> Number of obs: 578, groups:  Chick, 50
#> 
#> Fixed effects:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)  4.56520    0.06687  68.269  < 2e-16 ***
#> Diet2        0.21009    0.11283   1.862  0.06260 .  
#> Diet3        0.37956    0.11286   3.363  0.00077 ***
#> Diet4        0.33147    0.11299   2.934  0.00335 ** 
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Correlation of Fixed Effects:
#>       (Intr) Diet2  Diet3 
#> Diet2 -0.591              
#> Diet3 -0.592  0.350       
#> Diet4 -0.591  0.349  0.350

plot(independent.glm)
```

[image]

**Broad Question:** Independence matters, by why does it matter? What is happening when observations are dependent?

**Narrow Question:** Okay, independence matters (not sure why), but I'll account for it in my model using a multi-level structure. Why are the fixed effect coefficients changing? My understanding is that I've just fit a model at varying intercepts and not sure how that ties into fixed effects?

Comment: These are two big questions. With regards to the narrow question, see this thread. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/403693/are-covariates-in-a-mixed-model-estimated-between-group-within-group-or-somewh/404493#404493. Short take - once you switch to a multilevel modeling framework, you have partitioned the variance in the outcome (weight) into a level-1 within-chick and a level-2 between-chick component. The predictor of interest, if it varies within chicks, potentially has within- and between-chick variance itself, and this is showing up in the altered coefficient(s).