# Multilevel/ Mixed Model / HLM Centering Interactions Level 1 and Level 2 Cross-Level

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, mixed-type-data, mixed-random-variable

I am having some trouble with the literature on the correct model specification for my question.

Here is the setup:
I have a multilevel model with a variety of variables at level 1 and a single level 2 variable. I am examining interactions between both level 1 variables and cross interactions between the level 2 variable and other level one variables.

Here is an example:
X = level 1 variable
D = level 1 variable
Z = level 2 variable

The model I want is Y = X + D + Z + X*D + X*Z
Therefore, I have interactions between two level 1 variables (X and D), as well as a cross-level interaction (X and Z)

This is where I am having trouble figuring out the correct centering in the model. Where do I group-mean center and grand-mean center? What about the centering for the main effect terms? Also, should I be including any random slopes?

Comment: *Always* include a random slope for a level 1 variable that is involved in a cross-level interaction. Not doing so is anti-conservative in the sense that the resulting p-value will be too small - see Hesig & Schaefer (2019) at https://doi.org/10.1093/esr/jcy053.

Comment: In terms of centering, there are many threads on this on CV. For example, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/403693/are-covariates-in-a-mixed-model-estimated-between-group-within-group-or-somewh/404493#404493

Comment: Hi @ErikRuzek. Thanks for the information. I have seen that literature regarding including the random slopes for the cross level interactions. I guess my key question is then, should I center all level 1 variables within group and interact those centered variables with both the level 1 variable and level 2 variable? Then, allow random slopes for the centered level 1 variables?

Comment: I think centering within group makes a lot of sense for the variable involved with the cross-level interaction and it cannot hurt to center the other level 1 variables within group. For that second group of variables, you could also leave them uncentered and enter their group means in the model for the intercept.